# Airflow - 1st Friday of Every Month?

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow DAG that I am trying to have run for the 1st Friday of every month. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like a good case for a [custom Airflow Timetable class](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.0/howto/timetable.html).

Answer (score 0):

To schedule an Airflow DAG to run on the first Friday of every month, you can use the following cron expression in your DAG:

0 0 1-7 * 5